# How does Sum Square aggregation work and how to use it for the calculation of the Standard Deviation in icCube

Tags: iccube

One of the aggregation types in icCube is ["Sum Square"](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_aggregation.php).

I thought it would calculate the [sum of squares](https://www.westgard.com/lesson35.htm) as defined in the link, but I get different results.

What exactly is the Sum Square aggregation and how can I use it to calculate the standard deviation in icCube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how the algo to calculate the Variance and Standard Deviation in this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance).

You need count number of rows (n), sum of the rows (Sum) and the sum of squares (SumSq) :

```
Var = (SumSq − (Sum × Sum) / n) / (n − 1)
```

The Std Dev is the root of the variance (sqrt).

Comment: Thank you. A great option to calculate the standard deviation based on facts that are calculated during the load.